# Equivalent ruby code for python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, net-http

What is the equivalent ruby code for the following python code. I surfed net and find net/http' is the correct method. But I am new to ruby, I am unable to use this method effectively. Can anybody help me to write this in python?

**Python**

```
url = "https://www.abcde.com/api/"
post_data = "method=a&rate=2&order=asc"
headers =  {"key"=>"55208252", "sign"=>"4589cab68921fb43ad53149ea625e29"}

url_request_object = urllib2.Request(url, post_data, headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request_object)
```

Comment: have you realy searched web ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405717/urllib2-in-python-equivalent-for-ruby check this

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242602/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-open-uri

Comment: @RubyRacer - I have already seen this method. But I need to don't know how to pass headers with that

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар - I have seen this also. I want to pass headers also. so I don't know how to do it?

Comment: the signature of the correspondent method is just the same  in ruby http.post(url, data, header)

Comment: @Jeff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242602/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-open-uri see the second answer.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар - It allows only 2 params to get pass. I already tried

Comment: @jeff this one also https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature of correspondent method is the same

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', 3000)
headers = {'Content-Type' =>  'application/json'}
data = {:test => 'test'}

resp, data = http.post(path, data.to_json, headers)
```